# count mysql row data using Text

Tags: php, mysql

How can I count multiple MySQL table rows using text? currently I am using text(names) instead of numbers as values, I know how to count numbers but I have text with spaces where space is not allowed in MySQL.

my code looks like this.

```
$q = 'SELECT count(TS) as count FROM TABLE_TEST WHERE  
TS='.$db->qstr(Test Data).' GROUP BY id';
```

as we all know Space between Test Data is not allowed, how can I search using text?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: use quotes('/") for strings. `$db->qstr(Test Data)` should be `$db->qstr("Test Data")`.

Comment: Thanks you a lot. works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround strings with either single quotes or double quotes. Single quotes are better in PHP as they are not parsed for variables.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this:

```
    WHERE  TS LIKE '%Test Data%' GROUP BY id
```